# Could not find or load main class NERDemo

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Steps to recreate issue -

1. Clone from here https://github.com/BhanuMittal/namedEntityRltnship
2. Run NERDemo class (It's under Demo) using
   `java -cp "stanford-ner.jar:." NERDemo serializedClassifier nlp.txt`

I tried running above command while I was at these paths -
~/workspace/namedEntityRltnship/demo
and
~/workspace/namedEntityRltnship

Error is -
`Could not find or load main class NERDemo`

Here is what is expected to happen - 
Main method of NERDemo class will take the file as input argument and apply the classifier to classify the data present in text file using Stanford classifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run that command in a directory that has the `stanford-ner.jar` in it.

Also I would suggest just downloading the standalone NER directory we provide:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml